# What's the sintax of the pattern attribute for inputs?

Tags: html

I've been looking so much and I can't find a place where it explains the sintax to use in a pattern.
I don't understand some regular expressions, but for example I have to do this:
"A password that contains only 1 number in the beginning, 1 uppercase latter in the end, and mininum lenght of 8 characters (but can contain more)"
I already have this

```
<input type="password" minlenght="8" pattern="[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[A-Z]{1}"/>
```

This actually works, but is not the final solution that I want.
What I want to know, is, how can I say with a regex, between that first number and that last uppercase letter, that I don't care which character is written, and the number of them?

Answer (score 0):

It's a regular expression. Here's a link with some syntax info: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html. There are also some predefined ones that you could search for, like email, international phones, you can find the most common ones around the web.